# Typescript result of selected option

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have this code to send a message based on the user option (Now/Later) if the user chooses now it will send the message immediately, if later "I want to create a result for this radio button that will show a date format to set".

```html
<label for="">
  <input
    type="radio" 
    [value]="true" 
    formControlName="TimeOption" 
    (change)="onSelect($event)"
>
    Now
</label>

<label for="">
   <input
     type="radio"
     value]="false"
     formControlName="TimeOption"
     (change)="onSelect($event)">
   Later
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ngIf` directive to include a template depending on a condition. I created a working example from your snippet in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gpedzr?file=src/app/app.component.html

See more information about Angular directives in https://angular.io/guide/built-in-directives